# Como passar array em JavaScript para variável em PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Qual o melhor modo de transferir dois *arrays* em JavaScript para variáveis em PHP, segue minha ideia abaixo, funcionaria?

Função JavaScript

- array de datas de vencimento (`datasvenc`) no arquivo `cadastro_contratos.php`:

Está correto a criação do *array* em JavaScript e sua atribuição nos índices dentro do for?

```
function calculamensalidades(){

  var valortotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);
  var valorparcela = valortotal/document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value;
  var parcelas = parseFloat(document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value);
  var date = new Date();
  var mesvencimento = date.getMonth();
  var diavencimento = date.getDate();
  var datasvenc = new Array(6) 
  var tabela;
  tabela = "<br><table border='0' width='30%' style='text-align:center'><tr><td bgcolor='#4682B4'>Parcela</td><td bgcolor='#4682B4' >Valor</td><td bgcolor='#4682B4'>Vencimento</td></tr>";


  for(var a=0; a<document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value; a++)
 {
  var n_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), eval(a+mesvencimento), diavencimento);
  var diavec = date.getDate();
  var mesvenc = n_date.getMonth();
  var anovenc = n_date.getFullYear();
     tabela = tabela + "<tr><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>"+(a+1)+"</td><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>R$ "+valorparcela.toFixed(2)+"</td><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>"+diavec+"/"+mesvenc+"/"+anovenc+"</td></tr>";
     datasvenc[a] = diavec+"/"+mesvenc+"/"+anovenc;
 }
 tabela=tabela+"</table>";
document.getElementById("mensalidades").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("mensalidades").innerHTML=tabela;
 }

function apagatabela(){
document.getElementById('mensalidades').innerHTML="";
}

 function liberar()
{
  var total = document.getElementById("total"); 
  var parcelas = document.getElementById("select_parcelas");

  if(total.value != "")
  {
    parcelas.disabled=false;
  }
}
```

Atraibuindo ao php no mesmo arquivo cadastro_contratos.php:

esta correta a atribuição do javascript para o php?  `$dataVencimento = unserialize(base64_decode($dataVencimento));//Decode para array`

```
<div id="painelcadastro2" align="center">
<?php   if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
  $datacompra = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET['datacompra'])));
  $nomeProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nomeProduto1');
  $qtProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'qtProduto1');
  $valorProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valorProduto1');
  $valorparc = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valorparcela');
  $parcelas = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'select_parcelas');
  $entrada = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'entrada');
  $total = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'total');
  $status = "ativo";
  $dataVencimento = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'datasvenc');
  $dataVencimento = unserialize(base64_decode($dataVencimento));//Decode para array
  $pagamento = "CREDIARIO";
  mysqli_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
  mysqli_query("START TRANSACTION");
  $cadastracontratos = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO t_cadcontratos (Ficha, DataContrato, QuantParcelas, ValorContrato, Entrada, Saldo, DescricaoProduto, QuantProdutos, Vendedores, FormaPagamento) 
                          VALUES ('$nrFicha', '$datacompra', '$parcelas', '$valorProduto', '$entrada', '$total', '$nomeProduto', '$qtProduto', UPPER('$_SESSION[MM_Username]'), '$pagamento')");
  for($numparcelas=1; $numparcelas>$parcelas; $numparcelas++ ){
  $cadastraparcelas = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO t_cadparcelas (NumContrato, NumParcela, ValorParcela, DataVencimento, Status) 
                          VALUES ('$NumContrato', '$numparcelas', '$valorparc', '$dataVencimento[numparcelas]', '$status')");
  }
  if($cadastracontratos == '1' && $cadastraparcelas == '1') {
        mysqli_query("COMMIT");
        echo "Venda Crediário realizada com sucesso !";
  }else{
        mysqli_query("ROLLBACK");
        echo "Erro ao realizar a venda Crediário, tente novamente !";
  }
}
?>

<form id="adicionarformProdutos" method"post" action"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <a href="#" id="adicionarProduto">Adicionar Produto</a>      
    <fieldset class="fieldsetProduto">
        <legend>Produto 1</legend>
        <div class="produtos">
            <label for="codProduto1">Código:</label><input class="codigoProduto" type="text" id="codProduto1" size="5" name="codProduto1" />
            <label for="nomeProduto1">Nome:</label> <input type="text" id="nomeProduto1" name="nomeProduto1" size="9"  />
            <label for="qtProduto1">Qt.:</label> <input type="text" size="1" id="qtProduto1" name="qtProduto1" onblur="calcValor()" />
            <label for="valorProduto1">Valor und. R$:</label> <input type="text" id="valorProduto1" name="valorProduto1" size="6" onkeypress="mascara(this,float)" />
        </div>
     </fieldset>
<br>
            <label>Data da Compra <input name="datacompra" type="text" id="datacompra" size="6" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y')?>" onKeyUp="javascript:somente_numero(this);" onkeypress="formatar_mascara(this,'##/##/####')"/></label>
            <label>Desconto (%)<span style="display:none" id="sp_vdesconto"></span><input type="hidden"  name="vdesconto" id="vdesconto" />:<input type="text" name="desconto" size="6" value="0"id="desconto" onblur="calcValor()" /></label>   
            <label>Entrada R$<span style="display:none" id="sp_vdentrada"></span><input type="hidden" size="6" name="vdentrada" id="vdentrada" />:<input type="text" name="entrada" size="6" value="0"id="entrada" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" onblur="calcValor()" /></label>
<div>
  <br>
  <div>
            <label>Valor Total: <input type="text" name="total" value="0" size="6" id="total" onblur="liberar(); "/></label>
            <label>Qt. Parcelas: </label><select onchange="calculamensalidades()" disabled="disabled" value="" id="select_parcelas" name="select_parcelas">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
            </select>
 <div id="mensalidades"></div>
</div>
<br>
    <input type="reset" onClick="apagatabela()">
    <input type="hidden" name="cadastra" value="add"  />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nrFicha;?>" name="cadastro" />
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Cadastrar" />  
</div><!--fechando div painelcadastro2-->
</form><!--fechando div painelcadastro2-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona essa função dentro do seu método calcularmensalidades.

```
enviarViaAjax(){
    var dados = "&datasvenc=" + datasvenc; //Aqui você passa o array e as demais variáveis
    var xmlhttp; //Requisita o ajax
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); //se chrome/firefox/op vai usar XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else
    {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //se  IE ActiveXObject
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","arquivo.php",true);//Informa seu arquivo.php 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(dados);//Envia os dados
  }
```

No arquivo.php

```
$dataVencimento = $_POST["datasvenc"]; //Pega a info via post
$dataVencimento = unserialize(base64_decode($dataVencimento));//Decode para array
```

Ai basta você chamar seu sql para salvar o valor. Lá no javascript para você enviar o resto das suas variáveis você faz isso:

// var dados = "&variavel=" + variavel + "&variavel2=" + variavel2;

Comment: Olá Vinicius, obrigado! na verdade no meu código a função javascript é executada quando eu escolho o número de parcelas para que seja gerado uma tabela interativa, mas como posso inserir a requisição json sem um submit na minha função calculamensalidades() ?

Comment: Olá, no caso você quer mandar isso para o lado do servidor, sem banco de dados ?

Comment: Isso, quero enviar a uma variável PHP que encontra-se na mesma página, para que depois inclua no banco junto as demais variáveis PHP, aguardo!

Comment: Há entendi!!! 5 minutos por favor.

Comment: No caso então, vou colocar uma função a mais dentro do seu calculamensalidade que vai fazer isso para você.

Comment: Acho que é isso, qualquer coisa estamos aí. Fica a dica de trabalhar com jquery, ele já vem com ajax padrão que facilita muito sua vida. rsrsrsrs

Comment: Entendi, porém não necessitamos do arquivo.php pois a variável php esta no mesmo arquivo da função javascript... ai eu poderia ignorar o " xmlhttp.open("POST","arquivo.php",true);//Informa seu arquivo.php " ? Consegue exemplificar como ficaria na minha função? pois na função javascript tenho um for que preciso adicionar a cada repetição a data de vencimento... Obrigado!

Comment: Podes me informar se a criação do array e a atribuição da data nos seus indices esta correta? muito Obrigado!

Comment: No caso você deve usar o post e passar o nome do seu próprio arquivo no lugar do /arquivo.php. Tu diz as atribuições do seu código?

Comment: ok, isso! no caso a criação do array e a atribuição dentro do for :)

Comment: Amigo, editei a pergunta acima, somente naquele jeito seria que funcionaria? obrigado!

Comment: Seu código está ok sim! Por nada. Abraço

Comment: contando com a parte php ? vai acatar corretamente os índices ? tks

Comment: Isso aqui você faz depois de pegar uma requisição POST. $dataVencimento = unserialize(base64_decode($dataVencimento)); . Onde está o resto do seu código php que vai salvar esses dados? Como está mandando isso para o banco ?

Comment: ok, inseri na pergunta o que faço com este dado e os demais e insiro no banco e dados, esta correto? Porem esta ocorrendo erro no $cadastraparcelas pois parece que não localiza a variavel... Mas ai não tem haver com o que estamos vendo

Answer (score 1):

Experimete usar jquery, segue exemplo abaixo:

```
var numeros = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var letras = ['a', 'b','c','d'];
$.ajax({
   url : "arquivo.php" ,
   dataType : "json" ,
   data : {
       letras : letras ,
       numeros : numeros 
  },
success:function(){} ,
error : function(){}
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $numeros = $_REQUEST['numeros']; //Recebe numeros;
    $letras = $_REQUEST['letras'];  //  Recebe letras;

    print_r($numeros);
    print_r($letras);
//Faz o que tem que fazer e retorna em json

    return json_encoder($numeros);

?>
```

Mais informações no site da jquery.com

> http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Olá Douglas, obrigado! tens como me dar um exemplo com ambas variaveis no mesmo arquivo, sem precisar linkar a outra url em php... direto um POST e enfim ? tks

Comment: @RafaelAssmann não entendi o que tu precisa então, vamos reformular: Você precisa de saber como enviar alguns dados para um arquivo PHP (externo) ? Se for isso, é apenas seguir o exemplo que lhe dei. Mas caso não seja, por favor me explique novamente o que deseja.

Comment: interno, tenho a função javascript no topo do meu arquivo.php e logo abaixo a inserção no banco de dados em php e umas das variveis preciso capturar desta função javascript(array) e passa-la para php para depois inseri-la no banco, compreendeu ? podes me ajudar? tks

Comment: Posso sim claro. A primeira coisa que deve fazer é separar a lógica do HTML, depois você vai montar um formulário com todas as informações que tu necessita e por fim (ao clicar no botão de enviar, você vai fazer uma lógica no js para pegar todas as informações do formulário e enviar para o arquivo PHP via $.ajax.

Ficou claro ? Se desejar faço um exemplo para ti. Qualquer coisa só perguntar.

Comment: já faço isso, pego alguns campos do formulário html e faço calculos de alguns via javascript e insiro nas variáveis php para depois inserir no banco, mas meu problema está no array(não sei se esta correto), postei o resto do meu código na pergunta para ficar mais claro, abraço!