# Como salvar dados vindos do login SDK do facebook no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou usando a [api do facebook para login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4), e seguindo o tutorial já consegui implementar, mas ainda não entendi direito como funciona o sistema que pega as informações do usuário.

O que preciso é guardar estas informações no banco de dados (MySQL), pra assim identificar e associar o usuário com os formulários que ele preencher (não é formulário de cadastro, é tipo uma pesquisa, que pode ser respondida várias vezes pelo mesmo usuário).

Então, no meu banco de dados do formulário, queria criar algumas colunas pra incluir estas informações, e assim poder identificar quais (e quantos) formulários foram respondidos por cada usuário.

Quando faço o login, ele informa que estou concedendo permissões para pegar o e-mail e o perfil público, mas não sei onde estas informações ficam gravadas, e como faço pra jogar elas numa variável do PHP pra mandar pro BD.

O código que estou usando é o básico:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
        } else {
            // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
            // they are logged into this app or not.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
        }
    }

    // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
    // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
    // code below.
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
        });

        // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
        // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
        // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
        // the callback you provide.  They can be:
        //
        // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
        // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
        // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
        //    your app or not.
        //
        // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
    // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
        });
    }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Então **a pergunta é**: Como faço pra gravar as informações vindas do login com facebook no banco de dados MySQL, através do PHP?

Comment: na documentação, olhe o capítulo [Make API calls](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4#api-calls), o exemplo mostra como obter ID e email do usuário

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está utilizando o PHP, por que não usar também o [Facebook SDK do PHP](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/archive/5.0-dev.zip)? Vai ficar muito mais fácil obter e salvar os dados do usuário, já que você quer apenas isso.

Quando a pessoa clicar em botão que você colocar para login com Facebook, chame uma URL sua que execute o fluxo do SDK do Facebook.

Para instalar mais facilmente o SDK, adicione ao composer.json:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/graph-sdk" : "~5.0"
  }
}
```

## Exemplo básico fundamental de fluxo de login

**facebook.php**:

```
class Facebook
{
    private $helper;

    public function __construct()
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('SuaAppId', 'SuaAppSecret');         
        $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://seudominio.com/facebook-confirmado.php');
    }

    public function Login()
    {           
        $loginUrl = $this->helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
        header("Location: {$loginUrl}");
        exit;
    }

    public function GetSession()
    {
        try {
            $session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        }
        catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            // Trate erros do FB aqui
        }
        catch(\Exception $ex) {
            // Trate outros erros aqui
        }

        if($session)
        {
            // Logado, obtém informações do usuário
            $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'GET', '/me'
            ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

            return $user_profile;
        }
    }
}
```

**facebook-login.php**:

```
$facebook = new Facebook();
$facebook->Login();
```

**facebook-confirmado.php**:

```
$facebook = new Facebook();
$userProfile = $facebook->GetSession();

// User profile vai conter os dados do usuário:
// [id] => 4903490234934
// [email] => email@email.com
// [first_name] => Nome
// [gender] => male
// [last_name] => Sobrenome
// [link] => https://...
// [locale] => en_US
// [middle_name] => Nome do Meio
// [name] => Nome Sobrenome
// [timezone] => -3
// [updated_time] => 2015-06-06T03:29:08+0000
// [verified] => 1
```

## Como salvar informações do usuário

Assim, o nome, email e o ID Facebook do usuário estão no array `$user_profile`. E isso cobre a sua necessidade de obter e salvar os dados do usuário.

## Informações adicionais

Com o ID do Facebook você pode executar ações adicionais posteriormente, e isso depende de uma troca de tokens de acesso, mas está fora do escopo da sua pergunta. De qualquer forma, quando precisar, a referência é: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: +1 E eu chamo este arquivo `facebook.php` no mesmo botão do javascript skd? Ou não preciso usar o javascript sdk se for usar o php sdk? E sei que já ta fugindo do escopo da pergunta, mas pra eu salvar as infos na mesma linha dos dados do formulário vou ter que estar usando sessões né? Poderia dar uma dica do que tenho que estudar pra fazer isso (integrar o login do facebook às sessões do php...)... Valeu a ajuda.

Comment: Não precisa mais do Javascript SDK. Você vai colocar um botão normal e uma chamada normal a URL, exemplo: http://dominio.com/facebook-login.php. Para manter o usuário logado você segue o mesmo procedimento de um login "tradicional", armazenando na sessão/cookie/etc.

Comment: Ok, vou começar a tentar. Valeu!

Comment: Boa sorte! Como sua pergunta e problema principal foram resolvidos, seria interessante marcar a minha resposta como aceita.

Comment: Então Alfred, está difícil pra mim implementar o SDK PHP (sou iniciante ainda). Sua resposta me ajudou a entender melhor o problema (já dei +1), mas vou manter a pergunta aberta por mais um tempo, pra ver se aparece uma solução que me permita usar o SDK de JS e passar essas variáveis tipo [dessa forma](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39551/23400). Se isso não for possível, "Não é possível" também seria uma resposta válida... Valeu!

Comment: É mais que possível sim, eu apenas passei para você direto com o PHP, pois aí envolve só uma comunicação, sendo mais simplificado, devido a sua dificuldade original. Se eu lembrar, com mais tempo eu posto uma dica de como você deve fazer para fazer a comunicação JS <-> PHP.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in /home/ciclumcom/public_html/demo/fb/facebook.php on line 9