# Erro ao converter Array em Ajax para Array em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou com um erro ao tentar passar um array do ajax para o PHP e não consigo encontrar uma solução, tive como base [esta instrução, mas não consegui fazer funcionar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39510/como-passar-array-em-javascript-para-vari%C3%A1vel-em-php).

### HTML:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $produto['idarquivo']; ?>" >
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="customer_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $produto["idarquivo"]; ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $produto['idarquivo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $produto['arquivo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $produto['nome']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

No meu HTML tenho um botão que chama o seguinte arquivo javascript:

### Javascript

```
 $('#btn_delete').click(function(){

      if(confirm("Deseja deletar as linhas selecionadas?"))
      {
           var id = [];

           $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
               id[i] = $(this).val();
           });

           if(id.length === 0) 
           {
                alert("Selecione uma linha para deletar");
           }
           else
           {
                $.ajax({
                     url:'deletar.php',
                     method:'POST',
                     data:{id:id},
                     success:function()
                     {
                         alert ('sucesso');
                     }

                });
           }

      }
      else
      {
           return false;
      }
 });
```

Note que coloquei a seguinte linha `alert ('sucesso');` para ver se o código está funcionando, e o `alert` é exibido.

Porém não estou conseguindo passar o array `id` para o meu PHP de modo que ele funcione e delete as linhas no banco de dados.

### deletar.php

```
<?php include_once('conexao.php');

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    print_r($id);

    return json_encoder($id);

    $query = "DELETE FROM arquivo WHERE idarquivo IN $id";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);

?>
```

Comment: O que faz a função json_encoder? Ela me parece ser um erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor jeito seria fazer um jSON e passar para `data: {id:id}` assim, no PHP era somente decodificar e fazer um loop no comando de deletar. Mas uma solução possível rs, é a abaixo. Ele concatena cada ID e no PHP ele faz cada ID ficar como um item de array e executa o loop.:

**JS**

```
$('#btn_delete').click(function(){

  if(confirm("Deseja deletar as linhas selecionadas?"))
  {
    var id = '';

    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){
       id += $(this).val()+',';
    });

    if(id == '' || id == ',') 
    {
        alert("Selecione uma linha para deletar");
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
             url:'deletar.php',
             type:'POST',
             data:{ids:id},
             success:function()
             {
                 alert ('sucesso');
             }

        });
    }

  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php include_once('conexao.php');

$ids = $_POST['ids'];

print_r($ids);

$exp = explode(",", $ids);

foreach($exp as $id){

$query = "DELETE FROM arquivo WHERE idarquivo = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);

}
```

Comment: somente uma complementação, não faz parte da pergunta mas se conseguir me ajudar. Tem como eu usar um `.fadeOut('slow');` na `tr` da tabela para que cause um efeito da tabela sendo removida?

Comment: Como está a `<tr>` de sua tabela? Tem como jogar uma `<tr>` inteira aqui ?

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar POST ao inves de  REQUEST. Vê se dar certo! Na requisição `ajax` mude o `method:'POST'` para `type: 'POST'` e faça seu php assim e mude o ajax também!

```
$.ajax({
             url:'deletar.php',
             method:'POST',
             data:{id:JSON.stringify(id)},
             success:function()
        {
                     alert ('sucesso');
                 }

            });
```

PHP

```
<?php include_once('conexao.php');

$id = json_decode($_POST['id']);

print_r($id);


$query = "DELETE FROM arquivo WHERE idarquivo IN $id";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

?>

Comment: não deu certo, atualizei o post para que  você veja meu html se tem algo errado.

Comment: Atualizei minha respota . estava faltando uma chave nessa linha ```$id = json_decode($_POST['id']);```. Daqui a pouco dou olhada, estou apertado hoje rs

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, mas sua solução não funcionou.